# Rails routing error after scaffolding?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

So I'm receiving a routing error No route matches [GET] "/"

my routes.rb:

```
Webapp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :ideas
end
```

I scaffolded this ideas controller together by running this in my projects folder:

```
$ rails generate scaffold idea name:string description:text picture:string
$ rake db:migrate
$ rails s
```

& thats when I received the routing error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you have for   `root :to =>` in `routes.rb`?
This determines `[GET] "/"`

Comment: You, my friend have put a smile on my face. Thank you.. How did I not figure this out on my own.

Comment: No problemo. We all have those moments :)